# Swift dynamic button create

Tags: swift, xcode7, xcode8

I am new in swift.
I have created dynamic button by pressing another button in the same viewController with following code:

```
@IBAction func yenibtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)  //set frame
    btn.setTitle("btn", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor() //set button background color
    btn.tag = 1 // set button tag
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
    self.view.addSubview(btn) //add button in view



}
func clickMe(sender:UIButton!)
{
    print("Button Clicked")

}
```

and I created second viewController and navigate by `performSegueWithIdentifier` function. When i call back the previous controller the dynamic object disappears. Is there a way to retain dynamic button during reload of the previous ViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this:

```
   var btn:UIButton!
@IBAction func yenibtn(sender: AnyObject) {
btn= UIButton()
 btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)  //set frame
///... your code
}
```

**UPDATE**

Using your code in the second viewcontroller to close

```
 @IBAction func basgeri(sender: AnyObject) {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("bir", sender: self)
    }
```

thinking "I'm closing the viewcontroller", BUT YOU ARE WRONG! You create a new ViewController! You are not returning to the previous one!

To fix it use this:

```
 @IBAction func basgeri(sender: AnyObject) {

presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: I gives error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: When you see this
?

Comment: when i press button to run func yenibtn() function to create another button

Comment: it does not let me to write here all codes but basically two viewcontroller one of them has two button one navigate the  second viewcontroller the other one is to create another button dynamically. second viewcontroller has one button to return back to previous viewcontroller

Comment: It crashes here?  `btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)  //set frame`

Comment: try to debug and write here the line where it crashes

Comment: I can try this:

Comment: `btn = UIButton(type: .system)` or `btn = UIButton(frame:.zero)`

Comment: I fixed the bug but if i comeback back the page again dynamic button disappears.

Comment: @AlexGuba , please, understand me. It is not possible to find your bug without your code. The code your shown works as expected

Comment: Thank you it works! If it was open 3 pages like this, how to return from third page to first page without passing second page same way?

Comment: @AlexGuba , confirm if it was helpful

Comment: Thank you it was helpful to go first page. Is there any command to go any page? lets say page2 if it exist four page?

Comment: @AlexGuba , you can setup 'complition' callback in function I wrote. That is, completion: nil) >>>> completion: {/*your callback code*/})

Comment: You mean like this ?  self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {performSegueWithIdentifier("second", sender: self) })

Comment: As i understand navigation between pages should be hierarchical only you can dismiss the pages on the que without animation. There is no direct way to pass any page like go page3 or page9 directly  for one viewcontroller generated

Comment: @AlexGuba in brief yes. You can directly close unwanted pages, but, imho, this is not a good practise

Comment: @AlexGuba , i've answered to your several questions. so, approve the answer.